# android long keypress service

Tags: android, service, keydown

I am wondering if I could have an android service where it is started when either volume key has been pressed long(eg: 5 seconds). When the user holds down the volume button (eg: volume up) for 5 seconds then it starts the service and this doesn't interrupt when you want to raise the volume instead. 
Thanks in advance.